# Extract data from xml file (declaration) using R only

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to extract data from xml file that looks like this (see below). I need to extract **id** inside **nodes** for **node** where type=0. I have to find solution for R only.
For now I can extract type by *xmlToList("test.xml")[[3]][[1]]* and id by *xmlToList("test.xml")[[3]][[4]]*. Changing 3 to 6,9,etc - I can retrieve all of needed type's and id's. But I am not sure that this correct because it is based on numbering that can be changed (in case of xml structure change). Can you please propose another more simple way of extracting data from xml ? or any modifications on my nonideal solution? Thank's!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<image name="test1" id="367432589" width="952" height="1024" create_date="Mar 2, 2009" >
  <nodes>
    <node type="16" name="Target532" url="/cgi/im?id=5657" id="5657" x="67" y="45" width="153" height="69">
      <alt>Synthesis1</alt>
      <Appearance TextArea="Rectangle: 550"  Comlex="Boolean: true" />
    </node>
    <node type="0" name="Target1" url="/cgi/im?id=680" id="680" x="193" y="535" width="70" height="70">
      <alt>Object &lt;b&gt;Target1&lt;TestingCond32</alt>
      <Appearance TextArea="Rectangle: 210"  Comlex="Boolean: false" />
    </node>
  </nodes>
  <edges>
    <edge type="-100" id="234523">
      <alt />
      <Appearance Visualization="String: Hexa" HexagonIndex="Integer: 0" />
    </edge>
    <edge type="-100" id="23">
      <alt />
      <Appearance Visualization="String: Hexa" HexagonIndex="Integer: 0" />
    </edge>
  </edges>
</image>
```

I am new to xml and have basic knowledge of R. Thank you!

Comment: If you're new to parsing may I suggest looking at this thread on talkstats.com [(LINK)](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/26153-Still-trying-to-learn-to-scrape?highlight=scraping).  In this thread I ask a ton of beginner questions and Bryan Goodrich gives excellent advice and guidance.  I've been meaning to do a blog post on beginning scraping for a while..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
xpathSApply(xdata,"//*/node[@type=\"0\"]/@id")

> xpathSApply(xdata,"//*/node[@type=\"0\"]/@id")
   id 
"680"
```

This looks for a node that is named "node" with attribute "type" with a value of 0. It then returns the attribute value of id associated with this node

Comment: Sorry, I should I apply xpathSApply to xml or list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423931/extract-data-from-raw-html-in-r can u help for this question