# Getting nested data from xml file

Tags: xml, r

I have a `xml` file that is structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScheduleMessage DtdVersion="3" DtdRelease="0">
  <MessageIdentification v="ETSOVista-DMinus1TotalLoadForecast-DE-2012-1" />
  <MessageVersion v="1" />
  <MessageType v="A11" />
    <ScheduleTimeSeries>
    <SendersTimeSeriesIdentification v="10YCB-GERMANY--8" />
    <SendersTimeSeriesVersion v="1" />
    <BusinessType v="A05" />
    <Period>
      <TimeInterval v="2012-11-15T23:00Z/2012-11-16T23:00Z" />
      <Resolution v="PT60M" />
      <Interval>
        <Pos v="1" />
        <Qty v="52452" />
      </Interval>
      <Interval>
        <Pos v="2" />
        <Qty v="50527" />
      </Interval>
      <Interval>
       <Pos v="3" />
       <Qty v="49221" />
      </Interval>
      <Interval>
       <Pos v="4" />
       <Qty v="49344" />
      </Interval>
    </Period>
   </ScheduleTimeSeries>
   <ScheduleTimeSeries>
    <SendersTimeSeriesIdentification v="10YCB-GERMANY--8" />
    <SendersTimeSeriesVersion v="1" />
    <BusinessType v="A05" />
    <Period>
     <TimeInterval v="2012-11-16T23:00Z/2012-11-17T23:00Z" />
     <Resolution v="PT60M" />
     <Interval>
      <Pos v="1" />
      <Qty v="50935" />
     </Interval>
     <Interval>
      <Pos v="2" />
      <Qty v="48918" />
     </Interval>
     <Interval>
      <Pos v="3" />
      <Qty v="47347" />
     </Interval>
     <Interval>
      <Pos v="4" />
      <Qty v="46382" />
  </Interval>
 </Period>
</ScheduleTimeSeries>
</ScheduleMessage>
```

I only need the `Qty` values. So far my code looks like this:

```
xml <- xmlInternalTreeParse(file = "test.xml")
xml_top <- xmlRoot(xml)
xml_children <- xmlChildren(x = xml_top)
```

But when I try to get more deep into the file with:

```
xml_children2 <- xmlChildren(x = xml_children)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xmlChildren") : 
no applicable method for 'xmlChildren' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalNodeList', 'XMLNodeList')"
```

I also tried to subset the file using `[]` or `[[]]`, but it always guides me into the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using:

```
xpathSApply(doc = xml_top, 
            file = "//ScheduleMessage/ScheduleTimeSeries/Period/Interval/Qty", 
            fun = xmlAttrs)
```

Comment: Try this 
    //Qty/@v

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler with an XQuery processor such as `xqilla`:

```
$ echo 'for $v in //Qty/@v return xs:string($v)' | xqilla -i test.xml /dev/stdin
52452
50527
49221
49344
50935
48918
47347
46382
```

The output can then be read in easily using `read.table`. You might also be able to use the [`RXQuery`](http://www.omegahat.org/RXQuery/) package to run this within R, or as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379110/946850).

Credits: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947841/946850) to [Extract value of attribute node via XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4835891/946850)